# Is a semi-colon correct here or should it be a period?

Tags: commas, semicolons

Here's what I wrote. It feels wrong to start a sentence with "I tried that" as the reader wouldn't know what I'm talking about unless they read the previous lines, which is why I thought I'd use a semi-colon to join the 2 together, but now the sentence feels way too long. Is there a better way?

> To do this, you'll need to slowly build up your workload overtime, you can't just revise 10 hours straight, everyday single day; I tried that & I actually would have got more work done if I just worked 4-5 hours.

The full paragraph for context:

> In order to prevent yourself from quitting like last time, since no one is forcing you to study, you'll need to build discipline, or else you're just going to burnout a few weeks down the line. To do this, you'll need to slowly build up your workload overtime, you can't just revise 10 hours straight, everyday single day; I tried that & I actually would have got more work done if I just worked 4-5 hours.

Comment: The point of a semicolon is to clearly indicate the closely related nature of two independent clauses that would otherwise be separated by a period. But either semicolon or period can be used. It's just a matter of preference. (There is no problem starting one sentence that refers to another sentence that has just finished being read.)

Comment: You may assume any reader of one sentence has read the previous sentence.  Any who haven't, and are confused, will go back and read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mainly a matter of style.
But your second comma is a [comma splice](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/commasplice.htm), which is considered incorrect or poor style by a lot of grammarians.

So you could put either a semi-colon or a full stop (period in American English) in the place of the second comma. If the second comma becomes a full stop, then the second sentence is automatically shorter.

> To do this, you'll need to slowly build up your workload over time. You
>   can't just revise 10 hours straight, everyday single day; I tried that
>   & I actually would have got more work done if I just worked 4-5 hours.

If you prefer to replace the second comma with a semicolon, then for variation you could consider using a dash for the final section.

> To do this, you'll need to slowly build up your workload over time; you
>   can't just revise 10 hours straight, everyday single day -- I tried
>   that & I actually would have got more work done if I just worked 4-5
>   hours.

Comment: You mean the *second* comma is a comma splice. ;) (The first comma correctly delineates an introductory phrase and should not be changed.)

Comment: You're right, I missed that first comma. Will change. Thx.